# Interop Structure: Should Unsigned Short be Mapped to byte[]?

Tags: c#, interop

I have such a C++ structure:

```
typedef struct _FILE_OP_BLOCK
{                                                                                                                          
    unsigned short fid;     // objective file ID 
    unsigned short offset;  // operating offset
    unsigned char len;      // buffer length(update)
                            // read length(read)        
    unsigned char buff[240];
} FILE_OP_BLOCK;
```

And now I want to map it in .Net. The tricky thing is that the I should pass a 2 byte array for `fid`, and integer for `len`, even though in C# `fid` is an `unsigned short` and `len` is an `unsigned char`

I wonder whether my structure ( in C#) below is correct?

```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   public struct File_OP_Block 
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public byte[] fid;

        public ushort offset;

        public byte length;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 240)]
        public char[] buff;
    }
```

Comment: why do you use byte[2] instead of ushort/UInt16?

Comment: @jweyrich, that's because for certain reasons, the C++ code assign a two-byte array to `fid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CharSet property on the [DllImport] attribute is definitely wrong, you need CharSet.Ansi to get the P/Invoke marshaller to convert it to a char[].  Declare the buff member as a string for easier usage.  While declaring the fid member as a byte[] isn't wrong, I really don't see the point of it.  That the unmanaged code copies a char[] into it is an implementation detail.  Thus:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct File_OP_Block 
{
    public ushort fid;
    public ushort offset;
    public byte length;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 240)]
    public string buff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the C++ `short` data type is actually two bytes, a two byte array should work. The integer sizes in C/C++ are not strictly defined, so the standard only says that a `short` is at least two bytes.

The C# `char` data type is a 16 bit unicode character, so that doesn't match the C++ `char` data type which is an 8 bit data type. You either need an attribute to specify how the characters are encoded into bytes, or use a byte array.

You might need an attribute to specify the packing, so that there is no padding between the members.

Comment: I've put on an attribute, not sure whether that's correct or not.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: The layout settings looks correct. You should use Charset.Ansi to get an 8 bit character set.